# Binding of adjectives to two consequtive nouns

Tags: nouns, adjectives

Lets say I have a phrase `a valid geometry pointer` (which might be a little technical but the focus is on adjectives and nouns).

How does the word `valid` bind to `geometry pointer`? Does it mean `a (valid geometry) pointer` or a `a valid (geometry pointer)`?

Could you also point to a reputable resource that could confirm this? Thank you.

## Edit

or maybe its invalid in English?

Comment: It is too technical for me. You see, we need a context to deal with the ambiguity and I don't understand the context. Is there such a thing as a "geometry pointer"? In which case, I'd put those two together first. Or is there such a thing as "valid geometry", to which you have a pointer? We use context usually to sort this out.

Comment: @Margana both `pointer`, `geometry` and `geometry pointer` are valid entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyphenation can be used to avoid ambiguity in situations like this. Though this is more a matter of style rather than a solid, grammatical point.

For example, you can use a hyphen to place the emphasis as follows:

> A valid-geometry pointer.

or

> A valid geometry-pointer.

Source: [Economist Style Guide](http://www.economist.com/style-guide/hyphens) - see point four.

Answer (score 0):

It means

valid (geometry pointer)

The general rule is that you work backwards from the final noun. However this can be overruled depending on context, e.g.

a valid Euclidean Geometry pointer --->  a  valid ((Euclidean Geometry) pointer)

Maybe you could come up with better examples. Mine was made up.

Answer (score 0):

Either grouping of the two you gave is possible, but that might not be so if we were actually dealing with two adjectives.  "Geometry" is a noun, not an adjective.  "Geometry pointer" is not an adjectival construction, but is rather a compound noun -- that is, a noun made from the two nouns "geometry" and "pointer".

"Valid" is an adjective, which you would expect to modify a following noun.  In your example, there are two different following nouns it could modify.  One is "geometry" and the other is the compound noun "geometry pointer".